# Wronskian of complex second order linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have asked this question in Physics stack exchange earlier and am reposting here. While studying analogue models of gravity I have come across a differential equation of the form:
\begin{align}
\frac{d^2y}{dz^2} + \omega^2 (z)~ y(z) = 0
\end{align}
where $z$ is a complex variable and $\omega(z), y(z)$ are functions of the complex variable $z$.

- Am I right in saying that this equation models a dissipative system whenever $Im(\omega) \neq 0$ ?

Secondly, if the above equation contained only real variables and their real valued functions, we could have defined a Wronskian.

- Can I construct a Wronskian similarly here?

If yes, then that Wronskian should be a constant function of $z$, like a 'conserved quantity'.

- Does this contradict with the fact that the above differential equation is dissipative?

Comment: Indeed the Wronskian is constant. This is true whenever the coefficient of $dy/dz$ is zero. What do you mean by *dissipative*?

Comment: @yiorgos Yes, the Wronskian is constant whenever the condition given by you holds. If $\omega$ were a constant then a solution to the above equation would be $y = A exp(i \omega~z) + B exp(- i \omega~z)$. Depending on the sign of $Im(\omega)$ either of the two terms here will decay exponentially while the other will exponentially grow. In such cases, I have seen the term 'dissipative' being used if I have understood correctly. However, this is not very sound reasoning. The 'dissipative' label is improper/wrong here.

Comment: So, can one construct Wronskians of differential equations of complex variables just like in the real case? Do we have to satisfy some additional criteria for complex differential equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to @Yiorgos S. Smyrlis's comment: The Wronskian relates two linearly independent solutions, so it's not a conserved quantity in the usual sense, i.e. $F(y,y_z) = c$ which should hold for *every* solution $y$.

As for the dissipativity: this is somewhat open for interpretation, but if you would define a Hamiltonian in the 'usual' way, i.e.
\begin{equation}
 H(y',y,z) = \frac{1}{2} y'^2 + \frac{1}{2}\omega(z)^2 y^2,
\end{equation}
then
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} z} H = y'\left(y'' + \omega(z)^2 y\right) + \frac{1}{2} \omega \omega' y^2 = \frac{1}{2} \omega \omega' y^2.
\end{equation}
The only way you could call this 'dissipative' if the right hand side is negative. However, as you're dealing with complex valued functions, the concept of 'negative' doesn't really exist anymore, since the complex numbers don't have a natural ordering.

Comment: @fritzveerman I now understand what is meant by dissipativity. But, I could not grasp why Wronskian is not a conserved quantity in the usual sense when the coefficient of $dy/dz$ is zero.

Comment: See my answer: a conserved quantity is some combination of $y$ and its derivative which is conserved whenever $y$ is a solution of the second order differential equation you posted. A constant Wronskian merely gives a relation between two linearly independent solutions of the second order differential equation, i.e. something like $G(y_1,y'_1,y_2,y'_2) = c$. Specifically, you cannot use $G$ to reduce the dimension of the system, something you *can* do with a conserved quantity.

Comment: @fritzveerman Shouldn't there be no factor of $1/2$ before $\omega \omega' y^2$?